# In $O(2)$ a left-invariant form is not right invariant

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

We know that the space of left-invariant $1$-forms in $O(2)$ has dimension $1$ and we have a smooth group homomorphism $\lambda :O(2)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, where if we have that $\mu$ is a left-invariant $1$-form then $R_h^*\mu =\lambda(h)\mu$, where $h\in O(2)$. I also know that the expression for $\lambda$ is $\lambda(h)=det(Ad(h^{-1}))$, and that since $O(2)$ is a lie group $|\lambda(h)|=1,\forall h\in G$. Now I wanted to show that there is a value of $\lambda$ such that $\lambda(h)=-1$. Is there any good way of doing this without having to look at the local representation of the function $Ad(h)$? I wanted to avoid this since I am not interily sure what are the local coordinates for $O(2)$, since the way I proved it was a submanifold was using the regular value theorem. Any help is aprecciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100 percent sure about it, but here's what I think happens.

$O(2)$ is compact so the image of $\lambda$ is a compact subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^*$, so it's either $\{1\}$ or $\{\pm 1\}$.

$O(2)$ has two connected components, and the identity component is abelian so the restriction of $\lambda$ to it is abelian. So we're looking for an $h$ which is outside the  component of the identity. The simplest such one is h=$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$.

Now, if we look at tangent vectors instead of $1$-forms (the dual), we find that the actions of $(L_h)_*$ and $(R_h)_*$ as maps $T_{I_2}\,O(2) \rightarrow T_h\,O(2)$ are opposites one of the other. So, for any $1$-form $\tau$, $((L_h)^*\tau)_e=-((R_h)^*\tau)_e$. In particular, if $\tau$ is left-invariant (and doesn't vanish at $e$), the LHS is $\tau_e$, so this forces $\lambda(h)=-1$.

Comment: Are you saying that $d_e(L_h)+d_e(R_h)=0$ ,?(assuming the vector space structure) I am not sure this is true , might be confusing something. Also what do you mean by LHS? $Mindlack

Comment: LHS is short for "left-hand side". It's a bad habit I picked up by reading too many solutions on the internet. And yes, I guess that is what I meant. It's not that surprising, given that $h^2=Id$.

Comment: Okay now I see why it's true , I was forgetting of checking what the tangent space of $O(2)$ at the identity was , I was just assuming wrong stuff do to the canonical identification. Yes it will be true , thanks. @Mindlack

Comment: By the way I think I figured out a mistake, the claim about the differentials is true but since we are not in both cases making the differential an the identity. However if calculate the differential of $d_e(L_h\circ R_{h^{-1}})$ which is just $L_h\circ R_{h^{-1}}$ at the tangent space of the identity, which are the matrices with $a_1=a_4=0$ we will get -Id and so we will get that $\lambda(h)=-1$. @Mindlack

Comment: This way of thinking about it as $d_e(L_h \circ R_{h^{-1}})$ being $-id$ is nice, but I 'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: What I mean was that $d_e(L_h \circ R_{h^{-1}})=d_{h^{-1}}L_h \circ d_eR_{h^{-1}} $, and so I don't think the equaility that they are oppsites as linear maps at the tangent space at the identity helps since here we will be in differential tangent spaces, and so that's way I tried seeing what $d_e(L_h\circ R_{h^{-1}})$ is

Comment: $d_eL_h$ and $d_eR_h$ are two maps $T_eO(2) \rightarrow T_hO(2)$ so saying that one if the opposite of the other means something though... or perhaps I misunderstand your point?

Comment: Yes that is true, but my point was that we will be making $d_{h^{-1}}L_h$ and not $d_eL_h$ so I don't know how useful that information might be .